# Calculate expected values using logistic regression coefficients

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients

The outcome of the logistic model is binary (0;1) - intervention that occurs in hospital (3838 interventions in 51096 cases). I am modeling the effect of age groups (60 to 74; 75 to 89 and 90+) and sex (female) on the outcome. My reference age group is male aged 18-59.

My logistic regression coefficients look like this:

```
intercept  -4.313
female      0.5117
age 60-74   0.4081
age 75-89   1.1761
age 90+     1.5612.
```

Corresponding odds ratios:

```
female      1.668
years60_74  1.504
years75_90  3.242
years90     4.764
```

Now I am trying to obtain a probability of an outcome = 1 for each case. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: A few hundred closely related answers can be found by [searching our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=logistic+regression+coefficient+probability+is%3Aanswer+score%3A1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use an 80 year old women as an example. The relevant coefficients are -4.313, 0.5117, and 1.1761. Let us call that $X$. It is the linear predictor for the logit of the probability.

You have modelled
$$
\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right) = X
$$
exponentiating both sides and multiplying by $1-p$
$$
p = e^X - pe^X
$$
collecting terms in $p$ and factorising
$$
p(1 + e^X) = e^X
$$
dividing both sides gives us
$$
p = \frac{e^X}{1 + e^X}
$$
which can be further simplified to
$$
p = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-X}}
$$

Comment: @AlexD. You can "accept" mdewey's answer by clicking on the tick mark on the left of the text.