# Understanding how to get inverse logit?

Tags: regression, logistic, logit

I was watching a youtube tutorial that looked at logistic regression. To illustrate this they showed a graph that plotted p on the y-axis, where they used the inverse of logit(p).

Can anyone help me understand the algebra behind how they got from logit to inverse logit as below? Finding it quite frustrating to just see a black box output like this!

[image]

Comment: If you look at this question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236825/calculate-expected-values-using-logistic-regression-coefficients/236961#236961 you wil find the algebra worked out and a link to another question which also has further explanatory material.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. In that example, what is X? (I need more rep to comment on the answer)

Comment: In your example it is $\alpha$.

Comment: Yes but where does that come from? I know alpha= some number, but it's not intuitive to me how or why we are introducing it

Comment: It is the thing you got by using the logit() = from the left sub-panel of your example.

Comment: Oh okay that makes more sense now. So alpha isn't just "some number" really

Comment: In fact alpha isn't a number at all, but variable depending on p...

Comment: Your comments suggest some really fundamental confusion concerning functions and their inverses, darkace.  Would it help to rename $p$ as "$x$" and $\alpha$ as "$y$"?

Comment: That helps thanks. I forgot what an inverse function was as it's been a while